# OCI Error after updating to Mamp 4.5 on mac osx

Tags: mamp, oracle-call-interface

Hi guys I have a huge problem... after updating MAMP, every time I try to use a oci command the errors log displays:

```
[02-Jul-2018 13:59:40 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function oci_connect() in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/pcmdb.com-sviluppo.com/resources/pages/function.php:541
```

I have checked all my path and everything looks in the correct folder: /usr/local/instaclient.
I decided to delete and reinstall Mamp but still the problem happens.
I also added the extension=oci8.so inside php.ini :( 
Please help me

Answer (score -1):

I solved the problem following the instructions on php.net:

Setup
Testest with PHP 5.6, 7.0, 7.1, 7.2

Download the Oracle Instant Client for Microsoft Windows (32-bit) v.12 http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winsoft-085727.html
Unzip file: instantclient-basiclite-nt-12.2.0.1.0.zip
Copy all *.dll files: to c:\xampp\php
Copy all *.dll files to c:\xampp\apache\bin (Yes, a second copy!)
Make sure that the file c:\xampp\php\ext\php_oci8_12c.dll exists.
Enable php extension in php.ini: extension=php_oci8_12c.dll (For PHP 7.2+ use extension=oci8_12c)
Restart Apache
Click the Github ★ Star button :-)
Known issues
Especially the WAMP users reported that they still get the following error message:

PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'oci8_12c'.

In this case try to download the correct dll files from this link:

http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/oci8/2.1.8 -> php_oci8-2.1.8-7.2-ts-vc15-x86.zip
Connection test

Comment: Those steps are not applicable to macOS

Comment: Yes @ChristopherJones you are right, because I also moved on pc so I had the same issued resolved with the previous instructions, so... yes they are appropriate for XAMPP user